# How do I get the checked value from my checkedListbox?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, listbox, checkedlistbox

I'm writing a program for a colleague but don't know how to use the properties of all the items on Visual Studio C++ 2010.

I want to take the string that is selected or checked on the Listbox and Checked Listbox as well. On the first line of my code, when I take the List box char, it works perfectly, but when I try to do the same with my checked Listbox it gives me an exception.

Whats the property to only check one item on the Checked List Box?

```
char *nVuelo=((char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi((String ^)(LB_VisorVuelos->Items[LB_VisorVuelos->SelectedIndex])).ToPointer());
int pAsiento=((int)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi((String ^)(CLB_Asientos->Items[CLB_Asientos->SelectedIndex])).ToPointer());
```

Comment: Ohh , didnt knew that . And do you know what its the property to only check one?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you the C++ code (not a language I'm particularly fluent in), but maybe this will help.

`CheckedListBox` maintains a collection of the checked items in it's `CheckedItems` property. It contains all of the items that have been checked, and can be accessed using a typical `for` loop (C# code):

```
for(int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
{
  string selection = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i].ToString();
}
```

You can also use an enumerator and a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems) 
{
   string selection = itemChecked.ToString();
}
```

To check/uncheck an item in code, you use the `SetItemChecked(int index, bool value)` method:

```
checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(4, true);
```